# Why double is converted to int in JSON string

Tags: java, org.json

I just coded to put an array of double values in the `JsonObject`. But, all my double values are converted to int values, when i print it. can someone help me understand what is happening behind? Please let me know the best way to put primitive arrays in `JsonObject`

```
public class JsonPrimitiveArrays {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        double[] d = new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0};
        jsonObject.put("doubles",d);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);            
    }        
}
```

Output:

> {"doubles":[1,2,3]}

Comment: Is it localization issues?

Comment: I'm sorry.What do you mean by localization issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its in real not getting converted into int. Only thing happening is as JS Object its not showing `.0` which is not relevant.

In your sample program, change some of the value from `double[] d = new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0}` to

`double[] d = new double[]{1.0,2.1,3.1}` and run the program.

You will observer its in real not converting into int. The output you will get is `{"doubles":[1,2.1,3.1]}`

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [`toString` of `net.sf.json.JSONObject`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4/net/sf/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.toString%28%29) it eventually calls the following method to translate the numbers to `String` ([source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.java#JSONUtils.numberToString%28java.lang.Number%29)):

```
public static String numberToString(Number n) {
        if (n == null) {
            throw new JSONException("Null pointer");
        }
        //testValidity(n);

        // Shave off trailing zeros and decimal point, if possible.

        String s = n.toString();
        if (s.indexOf('.') > 0 && s.indexOf('e') < 0 && s.indexOf('E') < 0) {
            while (s.endsWith("0")) {
                s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            }
            if (s.endsWith(".")) {
                s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

It clearly tries to get rid of the trailing zeroes when it can, (`s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)` if a String is ending in zero).

```
System.out.println(numberToString(1.1) + " vs " + numberToString(1.0));
```

Gives,

```
1.1 vs 1
```

Answer (score 6):

All numbers are floats in Javascript. So, 1.0 and 1 are the same in JS. There is no differenciation of int, float and double.

Since JSON is going to end up as a JS object, there is no use in adding an extra '.0' since '1' represents a float as well. I guess this is done to save a few bytes in the string that is passed around.

So, you will get a float in JS, and if you parse it back to Java, you should get a double. Try it.

In the mean time, if you are interested in the way it displays on screen, you can try some string formatting to make it look like '1.0'.

Comment: +1, I learnt that all numbers in Javascript are floats and the zeros are removed to save a few bytes, thanks :)

Comment: Not sure if the answer is accurate since the question is about Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: @JasonCapriotti In the question, when a Java double array is converted into JSON, it looks like an integer array in the JSON string. I explained that there is no difference between float/double/int in Javascript. So, the ".0" is unnecessary. So the JSON library in java doesn't bother to add the ".0". I hope you understand that **JS**ON is **Javascript** Object Notation.